# Can I provide a type to a React component on forehand using a generic type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component that I would like to make more generic.

```
interface Props {
  arbitraryProp: CertainType | DifferentType;
}
const MyComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({ arbitraryProp }) => ( ... );
```

In the example there are two props provided. However, for each other implementation of the prop, in this example arbitrary, I would have to add it to that list:

```
interface Props {
  arbitraryProp: CertainType | DifferentType | YetAnotherType; // <- another one...
}
const MyComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({ arbitraryProp }) => ( ... );
```

Would it be possible to provide the type for that property on forehand, and than picking that up as a generic type?

So it would become something like:

```
interface Props<T> {
  arbitraryProp: T;
}
const MyComponent: React.FC<Props<T>> = ({ arbitraryProp }) => ( ... );
```

And using it would be something like:

```
<MyComponent
  // should have: CertainType
  arbitraryProp={certainThing}
/>

<MyComponent
  // should have: DifferentType
  arbitraryProp={differentThing} 
/>

<MyComponent
  // should have: YetAnotherType
  arbitraryProp={YetAnotherType} 
/>
```

Comment: Maybe check this - [interface with generics](https://youtu.be/IOzkOXSz9gE) (7:30)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Close one. It is similar but that's not using React. So the syntax can be quite different. And in this case that example does not work sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you'll need to declare the FC as a function, since there is no syntax that would allow arrow functions to be generic.

```
interface MyProps<T> {
  arbitraryProp: T;
}

function MyComponent<T>(props: MyProps<T>) {
  return ...;
}
```

(If you need the `children` prop that's injected by `React.FC`, you can add make the type of `props` `React.PropsWithChildren<MyProps<T>>` instead.)

Comment: Either `<MyComponent<Foo> ...>` or just `<MyComponent>` and let inference do its thing.

Comment: Oké. What should the return type be of a component that is not an React.FC? Any caveats of not using React.FC?

Comment: When in doubt, [peek at the types](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/f0df8a687be68aa4c8a5c461edf403ed12b0af56/types/react/index.d.ts#L547). An FC is basically a function that takes `(props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any)` and returns `ReactElement<any, any> | null` (plus some accoutrements for `propTypes`, `defaultProps`, ...). You don't need to use `React.FC`.